# redux toolkit property 'userReducer' does not exist on typ

Tags: reactjs, redux, toolkit

i have a problem. I have react project with redux toolkit, so i try get count number for my custom reducer, but i get error like - Property 'userReducer' does not exist on type '{ counter: CounterState; }'. What wrong for my code cant understand

```
 function App() {
const { count } = useAppSelector(state => state.userReducer)
const { inrement } = userSlice.actions
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

return (
<div className="App">
    <h1>{count}</h1>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch(inrement(10))}>Inrement</button>

</div>
);
}


 interface UserState {
user: IUser[];
isLoading: boolean;
error: string;
count: number
}

const initialState: UserState = {
user:[],
isLoading: false,
error: '',
count: 0
}

export const userSlice = createSlice( {
name: 'user',
initialState,
reducers: {
    inrement(state, action: PayloadAction<number>) {
      state.count += action.payload;
    }
  }
 })

  export const setupStore = () => {
return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer
})
 }

 export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Comment: what is the definition of `rootReducer`?

Comment: const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    userReducer
})

Comment: The error mentions `counterState`, but I don't see that anywhere in your code. Can you show the rest of the reducers and setup?

Comment: export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>

Comment: thats all my code from my project

Comment: i find solution, just write ts-ignore - const count: number = useSelector((state:RootState) => {
       // @ts-ignore
        return  state.user.count;
    })

Comment: Your `rootReducer` has to contain some reference to a `counter` or the error message would not be this way. Maybe you forgot to save a file after making some changes?